# Can anyone tell me why my array is not working with the function?

Tags: c

I am trying to create this program but I keep having errors saying that there is too few arguments in my function call. Am I doing this wrong? If anyone can explain where I am going wrong I think I can try to figure it out. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
// global declarations of arrays and variables
int levels[];
int pts;
void update_level (int pts, int levels[]);
void display_level (int k, int levels[]);
int main (void)
{
while (pts != -1) {
    printf("Enter a number (-1 to end) ");
    scanf("%d", &pts);
update_level(pts,levels[]);

}   
display_level(k,levels[]);
return 0;
} 

void update_level (int pts, int levels[]) {
if (pts >0 || pts <=9) {
    levels[0]++;
}
if (pts>9 || pts<=19) {
    levels[1]++;
} 
if (pts>19 || pts<=29) {
    levels[2]++;
}
if (pts>29 || pts<=39) {
    levels[3]++;
}
if (pts>39 || pts<=49) {
    levels[4]++;
}
else if (pts>49) {
    levels[5]++;
}

}

void display_level (int k, int levels[]) {
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    k = 1;
    printf("Level %d %10d", k, levels[i]);
    k++;
}

}
```

---

```
error msgs:
12  26  C:\Users\yuman\OneDrive\Fall2018\CIS 236 C++\.c files\Program 4.c   [Error] expected expression before ']' token

15  16  C:\Users\yuman\OneDrive\Fall2018\CIS 236 C++\.c files\Program 4.c   [Error] 'k' undeclared (first use in this function)

15  25  C:\Users\yuman\OneDrive\Fall2018\CIS 236 C++\.c files\Program 4.c   [Error] expected expression before ']' token
```

Comment: `update_level(pts,levels[5]);` -> `update_level(pts,levels);` (`levels[5]` here invokes *Undefined Behavior* because the valid indexes for `levels` are `0-4` -- and you are attempting to pass an `int`  (e.g. `levels[5]`) where a `pointer to int` (e.g. `levels`) is required)

Comment: The error message should give you details and a line number. Please include it in the question.

Comment: It looks like you are using the square brackets after the identifier, square brackets may be used in the declaration to show an array, but are not actually part of the identifier in the invocation.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** this is pre-edit where `levels[5]` was changed to `levels[]`, which does not fix the problem. You still have a confusion between an array and an element thereof. Another update below.

This line here:

```
update_level(pts,levels[5]);
```

The second argument is the sixth element of the `levels` array not the array itself. Your function is defined to require an array, not a scalar, and you're passing in a scalar.

Try either, define the function as:

```
void update_level (int pts, int a_level) {
```

Or pass in the entire array in the call, as:

`update_level(pts,levels);` **// UPDATE: note absence of "[]"**

This line here:

```
display_level(k,levels[5]);
```

Same problem.

Note that this only solves the immediate problem. I have not analyzed your code to find a "correct" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Declare of `int levels[];` should be `int levels[6];`.

In `display_level(k,levels[]);` statement, `k` is not defined. Need put something like `int k;` in `main` function.

You can call `update_level` and `display_level` like this `display_level(k, levels)`, `update_level(pts, levels)`.   Using `levels[]` is syntax error.